# Toggle classes with vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the class of an element in a nav bar.  The idea is a basic clickable hamburger icon that shows a nav menu when clicked on.

This is the HTML.  I'm trying to toggle the class name of the `ul` with the class of `header-list` to a class name  `header-list-open`.

```
<body>
  <!-- Start of Navigation Bar -->
  <header>
    <div class="nav-container">
      <nav>
        <h2 class="company-name">Sustained Garden Co</h2>
        <ul class="header-list">
          <!-- Navigation Links -->
          <li class="header-list-item"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li class="header-list-item"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li class="header-list-item"><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
          <li class="header-list-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <div class="hamburger"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- End of Navigation Bar -->
  <!-- Start of main content -->
  <main></main>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is the CSS that may be relevant.

```
.header-list {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header-list-open {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
}
```

This is the JS

```
var toggleClass = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
var classSwitch = document.querySelector('.header-list');

toggleClass.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('hello');
  classSwitch.classList.toggle('header-list-open');
});
```

I've tried this version of the JS code and several others.  The console is logging "hello" so the actual click is working.  Just not the class toggle.

Comment: `toggle` toggles the class you feed it. It doesn't change the name of a class.

Comment: @KevinB I think OP is trying to change the *name* of the CSS class from `header-list` to `header-list-open`... or so I read from the question.

Comment: I think either way it's just a misunderstanding of results. A quick look at the element in the browser console with it's computed styles would relatively quickly explain what's going on

Comment: The height is still zero and the overflow is still hidden.....

Answer (score 2):

When you apply the other class the other CSS rule is still being applied so your CSS is now:

```
.header-list {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
}
```

So you either need to remove the class header-list or set the height and overflow in the open class.

Or instead of setting the height/overflow, why don't you just set the display to none and set it to block in open?